# Calculation of $\int_{M}R_{ij}\nabla^{i}\varphi\nabla^{j}\varphi\; e^{-\varphi}d\mu$.

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I am trying to calculate the following:
\begin{equation}
\int_{M}R_{ij}\nabla^{i}\varphi\nabla^{j}\varphi\; e^{-\varphi}d\mu=\int_{M}\nabla^{i}R_{ij}\nabla^{j}\varphi\;e^{-\varphi}d\mu+\int_{M}R_{ij}\nabla^{i}\nabla^{j}\varphi\;e^{-\varphi}d\mu.
\end{equation}

I have this calculated:
\begin{equation}
e^{-\varphi}R_{ij}\nabla^{i}\varphi=e^{-\varphi}\nabla^{i}R_{ij}-\nabla^{i}(R_{ij}e^{-\varphi}).
\end{equation}
So i got that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{M}R_{ij}\nabla^{i}\varphi\nabla^{j}\varphi\; e^{-\varphi}d\mu&=\int_{M}(e^{-\varphi}\nabla^{i}R_{ij}-\nabla^{i}(R_{ij}e^{-\varphi}))\nabla^{j}\varphi\;d\mu\\&=\int_{M}\nabla^{i}R_{ij}\nabla^{j}\varphi\;e^{-\varphi}d\mu-\int_{M}\nabla^{i}(R_{ij}e^{-\varphi})\nabla^{j}\varphi d\mu.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Now, I have the following:
\begin{equation}
\nabla^{i}(R_{ij}e^{-\varphi})\nabla^{j}\varphi=\nabla^{i}(R_{ij}e^{-\varphi}\nabla^{j}\varphi)-R_{ij}\nabla^{i}\nabla^{j}\varphi\;e^{-\varphi}.
\end{equation}
Then I have
\begin{equation}
\int_{M}R_{ij}\nabla^{i}\varphi\nabla^{j}\varphi\; e^{-\varphi}d\mu=\int_{M}\nabla^{i}R_{ij}\nabla^{j}\varphi\;e^{-\varphi}d\mu+\int_{M}R_{ij}\nabla^{i}\nabla^{j}\varphi\;e^{-\varphi}d\mu-\int_{M}\nabla^{i}(R_{ij}e^{-\varphi}\nabla^{j}\varphi)d\mu.
\end{equation}
I cannot remove the last term from the above equation. The only idea I have is to use the divergence theorem, but it doesn't appear in the equation.

Comment: Is $M$ compact? If it is, then the last term is equals to zero, since the Divergence Theorem.

Comment: Yes, $M$ is compact. But how do you use the divergence theorem in this case? I don't see it very clear.

Comment: $\nabla^i(T_i)$ is the divergent of the tensor $T_i=R_{ij}e^{-\phi}\nabla^j\phi$.

Comment: $R_{ij}e^{-\varphi}\nabla^{j}\varphi$ is a escalar fuction, why is it a tensor?

Comment: It has i as an index, so it is a tensor.

Comment: I am confused because the definition of divergence I understand is using the nabla operator as follows: $\nabla_{i} T^{i}$ when $T=T^{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}$. For me, this is the definition of divergence. I don't understand the meaning of $\nabla^{i}(T_{i})$. I made a mistake?

Comment: Is $M$ Riemannian and $\nabla$ the Levi-Civita connection? In that case you can just rise and lower indices and $\nabla^iT_i=\nabla_iT^i$.

Comment: Could you recommend me literature to review these properties?

Comment: Do you understand the notation $\nabla^i \varphi$ and how it is different from $\nabla_i \varphi$?

Comment: Yes. The first ones are the gradient components of a scalar function and the next one is the covariant derivative of a scalar function.